# Namespace 'google.maps.marker' has no exported member 'AdvancedMarkerView'

Tags: typescript, google-maps, react-hooks, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to use Google maps Advanced Markers but my code does not recognizes it.

I'm following a video tutorial from google's youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxYqoY2WwE&t), and using the beta version as teached, but it still does not recognizes AdvancedMarkerView.

Here's my code:

calling the beta version and the right libraries:

```
export default function CorretoresMap({ data }: { data: Broker[] }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper
      apiKey={import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_API_KEY}
      version="beta"
      libraries={["marker"]}
    >
      <Map data={data} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

This Marker component is called inside Map. The error apears in the code below:

```
function Marker({
  map,
  position,
  children,
}: {
  map: google.maps.Map | undefined;
  position: { lat: number; lng: number };
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    //in this line i get the error: the namespace 'google.maps.marker' has no exported member 'AdvancedMarkerView'
  const markerRef = useRef<google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView | null>(null);
  const rootRef = useRef<Root | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!rootRef.current) {
      const container = document.createElement("div");
      rootRef.current = createRoot(container);

      //in this line i get the error: the property 'AdvancedMarkerView' does not exist in the 'typeof marker'.
      const markerView = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
        position,
        content: container,
      });

      markerRef.current = markerView;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rootRef.current) {
      rootRef.current.render(children);
    }
    if (markerRef.current) {
      markerRef.current.position = position;
      markerRef.current.map = map;
    }
  }, [map, position, children]);

  return null;
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Hey Luca, can try to run your code without the type annotation in that line ?
Instead of `const markerRef = useRef<google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView | null>(null);` can you use `const markerRef = useRef();` and check if that works?

Comment: Thank you Dirk! I ended up solving the problem by using AdvancedMarkerElement instead of AdvancedMarkerView, and inporting it using `const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker") as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;` inside the marker component. Maybe AdvancedMarkerView is deprecated... still don't know why it didn't work. @DirkSchiller

Comment: @Luca I think `AdvancedMarkerView` was only available in the [beta channel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.51/advanced-markers). `AdvancedMarkerElement` is the way to go.